# How to check for Cognito permissions in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, amazon-cognito

Trying to understand how to use Cognito and API Gateway to secure an API.

Here is what I understand so far from AWS documentation and the Cognito user interface:

**Clients**

- www-public - public facing website
- www-admin - administrators website

**Resource Servers**

- Prices - for this simple example the API will provide secured access to this resource.

**Scopes**

- prices.read
- prices.write

Again, very simple permissions on the API. Public www users can read prices, administrators can write them.

**API Gateway**

- GET /prices - accessible to authenticated users that can read prices.
- POST /prices - only accessible to administrators

**Users**

- Administrators - can update prices via the POST method.
- Non-administrators - cannot update prices.

Based on this...

- Each client will request the scopes it is interested in. So for the public www site it will request `prices.read` and for the administration site both `prices.read` and `prices.write`.
- The API Gateway will use two Cognito Authorisers, one for each HTTP Verb. So the `GET` method must check the user can *read* prices and the `POST` method that they can *write* prices.

The bit I don't see is how to put all of this together. I can make the clients request scopes but how do they now connect to user permissions?

When the token is generated, where is the functionality that says "Ok, you requested these scopes, now I'm going to check if this user has this permission and give you the right token?"

I understand that scopes ultimately related to the claims that will be returned in the token.For example, requesting the `profile` scope means that the token will contain certain claims e.g. `email`, `surname` etc.

I *think* based on this that my permissions will ultimately end up being claims that are returned when specific scopes are asked for. The fact that the two clients differ in what they request means that the `prices write` claim an never be returned to the public www client. It would never issue a token if the `prices.write` claim was requested.

What I can't see is where this fits in Cognito. There is the option to put users into groups but that is pretty much it. Likewise, there is nothing (that I could see) to relate scopes to claims.

I'm coming from a .Net and Identity Server background. Certainly in the last version of Identity Server I looked at there was a handler method where you would work out which claims to put into a token. I guess this would map into one of the custom handler lambda functions in Cognito. From there this would need to query Cognito and work out what claims to issue?

The final piece of the puzzle is how the API Gateway checks the claims. Can this be done in API Gateway or does the token need to be inspected in the Lambda function I will write to handle the API Gateway request?

Certainly using Identity Server and .Net there was a client library you would use in the API to inspect the claims and redact permissions accordingly. Guessing there is something similar in a Node JS Lambda function?

A few assumptions there as I'm basically in the dark. I think the basics are there but not sure how to connect everything together.

Hoping someone has figured this out.

Comment: Trying to figure it out myself. The scopes will be returned as a space-separated list in the access-token's "scope" claim, but no idea how to associate them to users/groups.

Comment: any luck on this? stuck at the same point (associating scopes to users)